# How to play videos in pyglet 2.0?

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm writing a game using Python Arcade which requires pyglet-2.0dev9, and trying to play a video between levels of the game.

To start simple, I tried running pyglet's sample media player (https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/master/examples/media/media_player.py) from the command line. It works well with my mp4 video file when I have pyglet 1.5.21 installed, but it fails with pyglet 2.0-dev9 and dev11. I worked through one issue relating to displaying the GL video controls (I commented these out), but now I get this traceback when I run it:

```
  File "/Users/bernard/projects/gralli_quest/media_player.py", line 369, in on_draw
    video_texture.blit(self.video_x,
  File "/Users/bernard/.pyenv/versions/gralliq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyglet/image/__init__.py", line 1424, in blit
    pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(4, GL_TRIANGLES, [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3],
  File "/Users/bernard/.pyenv/versions/gralliq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyglet/graphics/__init__.py", line 262, in draw_indexed
    glDrawElements(mode, len(indices), index_type, index_array)
  File "/Users/bernard/.pyenv/versions/gralliq/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyglet/gl/lib.py", line 114, in errcheck
    raise GLException('(0x%x): %s' % (error, msg))
pyglet.gl.lib.GLException: (0x502): Invalid operation. The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.
```

I compared the version of media_player.py in the pyglet repo under the dev7 tag with the one in master and it was the same. I tried [a different video player sample script for pyglet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pyglet-play-media-in-player/) and get the same result. I tried looking up docs for pyglet 2.0 but could not find them.

Comment: It seems that example needs a rewrite since it's using deprecated fixed pipleine calls. It won't even run at them moment.

Comment: Thanks for checking that, Grimmy. If anyone knows another way to play videos in pyglet 2, it would be very helpful. If not, I may have to try including two versions of pyglet in my project, which could get ugly.

Comment: Definitely don't mix pyglet 1 and pyglet 2. That won't work well. It should not be too difficult to fix the video example i 2.0 to be honest. The fixed pipeline calls just needs to be replaced.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a sol'n for this, einarf just opened a (WIP a of today) PR that addresses most of the problems: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/pull/510